# Could it be a way out to load data url

Tags: data-uri, base64url

I have this JavaScript code and Html code.
The codes refreshed and load the dataurl but this code stopped working on 2017, browsers no longer load it.

Html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">    

  <head>      

    <title>news update</title>      

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=''" />    

  </head>    

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.location=""

</script>
```

This is already 2019, it will be great some high knowledge guys have solution to this already.
Thanks

Comment: `window.location.href` may have better support, depending on your circumstances (browser, framework, operating system, etc.)

Comment: I tried `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://www.google.com'" />` and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  normal url works fine, but dataurl that's bas64 doesn't,  something like thus: data:text/html:base64 url doesn't.  Thanks